# Can we [cite] this for being vague?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[cite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cite) - 35 questions

This tag has no usage guidance. It has a very short tag wiki that says it should be used for the HTML `<cite>` tag, but people don't tag their questions properly. Questions tagged with it are all talking about  a different kind of "cite."

- Citing a drive | [sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory on cited drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758125/sh-0-getcwd-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-on-cited-drive)
- HTML `<cite>` tag | [What is the purpose of the blockquote attribute ''cite'' in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051983/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-blockquote-attribute-cite-in-html)
- Citing sources in a bibliography | [Can I cite an institution without using a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715121/can-i-cite-an-institution-without-using-a-year)
- Citing permission to use copyrighted images | [How do you cite permissions of images on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847820/how-do-you-cite-permissions-of-images-on-a-website)
- A MediaWiki extention named "Cite" | [Cite Option Not Showing using WikiEditor - WikiMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462360/cite-option-not-showing-using-wikieditor-wikimedia)

What should be done with this tag? Split it up into tags such as [html-cite] and [bibliography-cite]? Straight-up burninate it?

Comment: Suggested title: Can we [cite] this for being vague?

Comment: 35 questions is under the limit of 50 for the full burninate. That means if we have two [trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) are knowledgeable on the relevant technologies and on board, we can go ahead without waiting for it to get featured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and did a lot of retags, since the tag was meta to the question (`<cite>` is covered by [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and/or [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5)). Turns out we just recommend Latex questions be put on Tex.SE, and that's not a hard and fast rule (if they were younger would have migrated them).

There's 4 closed questions left. I've asked the mods to finish them off, which will remove the tag.